# play FLV video in a SWF object

Tags: flash, embed, flv, swfobject

Here is the problem: I have to redo the site, with less flash as possible. Old site used swf object with flv video file which had transparent background. I have the flv video, but I can't embed it on the page. Is there a way to do this using code below, or something similar to this? Or I have to create new swf object with video embedded into it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {
            allowScriptAccess:'sameDomain',
            wmode: "transparent",
            scale: "allowscale"
        };
        var attributes = {
        id:'logo',
        name:'logo'
        };
        swfobject.embedSWF("logo.flv", 
                       "flash_content", 
                       "126px", "117px", "9.0.0", 
                       "expressInstall.swf", 
                        flashvars, 
                        params, 
                        attributes);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWFObject is not a video player, it is a utility for embedding SWF files into HTML documents. FLV files can only play when loaded into a SWF-based player.

You need to either build a SWF that can load/play your FLV (there are many [tutorials](http://flashartist.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/how-to-create-a-custom-flv-player/) online), or use a 3rd party video player, such as [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/).

Comment: I was afraid of that, I would like to use swf based player that is currently being used on the site. I just needed to confirm this things with someone more experienced. Thanks